# How tho get the whole section with regex (until a line doesn't start with whitespace )

Tags: c#, regex

I have the next string:

```
Numbers: Zero
     One
   Two
    Three
  ***
  (n lines that start with one or more whitespace chars)
  ***
Name\Fruits\etc: John
  Jane
```

I want to get (with regex) the string that starts with "Numbers:" until the next line that starts with non-whitespace character (without this line...).

I my example, the next line after "Numbers:" that starts with non-whitespace character is: "Name\Fruits\etc: John", so I want to get:

```
  Zero
     One
   Two
    Three
  ***
  (n lines that start with one or more whitespace chars)
  ***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
^(?:Numbers:)([\w\W]+?)(?=^\S)
```

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- (?:Numbers:) - Non capturing group, matches `Numbers:`.
- `([\w\W]+?)` - Match anything. ( lazy mode ).
- `(?=^\S)` - Must be followed by newline with non space character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fLSyED/5/)